# Usage of dashboard variable in queries

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I'm fairly new to grafana and I am confused how to solve this elegantly:

I have a custom dashboard variable ["device1", "device2", "device3"].
I know how to use the $(variablename) Syntax to query for the currently selected option.

But in an overview dashboard I want to query for all 3 devices from the variable.
Is there a way to use the actual array instead of the currently selected option in queries?
Or is there any other way that I could define a set of values **per org** by which I then can query?

Thx

Comment: Use "multi-value" variable type (or define "All" value) and then format variable properly for your datasource https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of this option. It is not exactly what I'm aiming for though.
I want it to be invisible for the user (no dropdown menu at the top of the dashboard) and I can't seem to do it with the variables.

Comment: You can hide env variable, so it will be invisible for the user in the ui.